# Offline sync in xamarin forms without azure mobile service client

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin development.

I am building a Xamarin application with RESTful API and using SQL server for online storage and SQLite for the Local storage.

I need to add offline sync feature to my app.

Is there any way to sync remote server and local DB, without using azure mobile service client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can make use of Sync Adapter this would sync your data in background but this is Platform specific and hence you had to implement it in Native Class Also If you want a Periodic Sync you can also use JobSchedular in Android

You Can Read More Here
[Android SyncAdapter Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/)