# Xamarin Offline First Solution for UWP without Azure or Realm

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

Very new to Xamarin, so I am unaware of all of its capabilities.

I am creating a Xamarin app that focuses on offline first. By this, I mean that I can use the app when there is no device connection for data storage and syncing. I have done some research and a lot of the documentation seems to be on using [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/sync/azure-mobile-apps) (Azure Mobile App), [Realm](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Episode-20-Realm-Mobile-Databases-with-Adam-Fish), or another paid service. I would like to stay away from that.

A few things:

- This app is mostly focusing using Xamarin Forms to create **UWP** only for now. I can put aside the Android and iOS portions for now. But it is something to keep in the back of my head because the application will eventually be on Android and iOS.
- I will be getting data from another SQL database remotely, and storing it locally on the device.
- I should be able to update the records locally first in case there's no connection. This will make the experience seamless to the user, so they are not interrupted with any lag.
- When there is connection, device will sync local data with the remote server.

I know that there is a good chance that I will need to do use native UWP offline solutions. Is there any documentation on how to do that through Xamarin or examples/samples? Could using the [SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) for Xamarin accomplish what I want without the use of Azure Mobile?

I have seen something like this being done through Xamarin for the Android side: [Offline sync in xamarin forms without azure mobile service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134364/offline-sync-in-xamarin-forms-without-azure-mobile-service-client) using the SyncAdapter in Android. Anything for UWP like that would be great.

Comment: Is it so that you want the syncing with the remote server to happen in the background only(Autosync)? Or will you be adding a button or something for syncing?

Comment: @G.hakim, To simplify things, we can start with syncing with a button for now. Later on, autosync would be ideal for the app.

Comment: Look over this document on using a local database with Xam.Forms. Should work in Xam.Forms app for UWP, Android, and iOS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases . Getting the data from your SQL server is another issue. You want to create a web RESTful API that your app can onnect to and the web RESTful API will then connect to your SQL database )you do not want to make the SQL database available to the entire internet, and creating a web service allows you to configure your SQL database to only accept connections from that web service's IP address.

Comment: Thank you @jgoldberger-MSFT. Is there any documentation or examples on filling the local SQL database (SQLite) vis RESTful web API through Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is irrelevant here. And there is no one answer as every RESTful web API can be different. My suggestion was that you create your own RESTful web API that connects to your existing SQL database. But what may be easier to get started offline is to just manually get the data from your SQL database and then use a SQLite browser (https://sqlitebrowser.org/ ... 3rd party, use at your own risk) tool to create your SQLite database file. You can then include that database file in your app resources, then when your app runs, copy the file to a usable file location outside of your app.